# Haskell apply Code for Get/Https to Post/HTTP

Tags: haskell, post, proxy, get

I have code which works with a post request and proxy for `htpp://` sites:

```
main = do
  rsp <- browse $ do
    setProxy . fromJust $ parseProxy "128.199.232.117:3128"
    request $ getRequest "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yj_wyw6Xrq4"
    --request $ postRequestWithBody "http://www.youtube.com/service_ajax" "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "se=8pH38AERCAASDQoLeWpfd3l3NlhycTQ%3D&itct=CDMQpUEiEwiS-rKDqN7JAhXQFxwKHeLMCi8o-B0"
  print $ rspBody <$> rsp
```

And I have code which works with a get request and proxy for `https://` sites:

```
main = do
    req <- parseUrl "https://github.com/"
    let settings = mkManagerSettings (TLSSettingsSimple True False False) Nothing
    manager <- newManager settings
    let ret = addProxy "128.199.232.117" 3128 req
    res <- httpLbs ret manager
    print res
```

My aim: Have code which works with a post request and proxy for `htpps://` sites.

My problem: I'm not skilled enought to apply the `https://` comatible code to my post request.

Could someone show me the solution please? Thanks

Comment: Side note: `fromJust` is bad practice because it can fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parseURL` function returns a `Request`, that you can configure to set proxy, HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT etc), headers etc. For example, to set a method, use `method` record selector. From the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.8/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#t:Request):

```
initReq <- parseUrl "http://www.example.com/path"
let req = initReq
            { method = "POST"
            }
```

To set request body:

```
let req = initReq
            { method = "POST"
            , requestBody = RequestBodyBS "body itself as a ByteString"
            }
```

Comment: and how to set the data which should be posted?

Comment: must I replace `"body itself as a ByteString"` with my data `"t=12wwe2&args=aafe32"` ?